# want get a efficient hash function

Tags: hash, julia

in my program, I will get a lots of key-value pairs, contain duplicated keys, I need to merge key-value pairs with same keys.
The keys are integers and values are complex number, actually they represent a sparse vector. The integers have the property that the binary code have specific length and have specific number of 1's.

Before, I use a sort method to merge the same keys. I store keys and values in two array, and sort the keys, also permute the values, then I add the values with same keys, so get the result.
But I want to improve the performance, I tried use hash function.
I tried use dict in julia, I add key-value pairs one by one, but I find the speed is almost the same.

I want to know how can I find a hash function very suitable for this case, the inputs are integers have specific length of binary code and specific number of 1's in binary code.

I know maybe I need to test my code for different size of data, I want to improve the hash function first.
Thank you in advance!

add some code and test:

```
using SparseArrays
using StatsBase
using TimerOutputs

n_qubits = 30
N_e = 10
function get_basis(n_qubits::Int64, N_e)
    basis_num::Int64 = factorial(big(n_qubits))/factorial(big(N_e))/factorial(big(n_qubits-N_e))
    basis_set = Array{Int64, 1}(undef, basis_num)
    count::Int64 = 0
    for i in 0:(2^n_qubits-1)
        if count_ones(i) == N_e
            count += 1
            basis_set[count] = i
        end
    end
    return basis_set
end

basis_num = 2^16
basis = get_basis(n_qubits, N_e)
sp_len = min(basis_num, length(basis))
idx = sample(1:length(basis), sp_len)
sp_row::Vector{Int64} = basis[idx]
sp_val::Vector{ComplexF64} = rand(sp_len) + rand(sp_len) * im


function get_dict(dict_size::Int64)
    @time res_dict::Dict{Int64, ComplexF64} = Dict{Int64, ComplexF64}(zeros(UInt8,dict_size), zeros(Int64,dict_size), zeros(ComplexF64,dict_size), 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
    @time for _ in Base.OneTo(10)
        for i in eachindex(sp_row)
            if sp_row[i] in keys(res_dict)
                res_dict[sp_row[i]] += sp_val[i]
            else
                setindex!(res_dict::Dict{Int64, ComplexF64}, sp_val[i]::ComplexF64, sp_row[i]::Int64)
            end
        end
        empty!(res_dict)
    end
    println()
end

get_dict(2^19)
for i in 10:22
    println(i)
    # get_dict(2^i - 1)
    get_dict(2^i)
    # get_dict(2^i + 1)
end


println()

@time for _ in Base.OneTo(10)
    sparsevec(sp_row, sp_val)
end
@time for _ in Base.OneTo(10)
    sparsevec(sp_row, sp_val)
end
@time for _ in Base.OneTo(10)
    sparsevec(sp_row, sp_val)
end
```

and the outputs

```
10
  0.000005 seconds (4 allocations: 25.391 KiB)
  0.019551 seconds (23 allocations: 8.302 MiB)

11
  0.000006 seconds (5 allocations: 50.438 KiB)
  0.016879 seconds (17 allocations: 4.102 MiB)

12
  0.000092 seconds (6 allocations: 100.359 KiB)
  0.019492 seconds (18 allocations: 8.204 MiB)

13
  0.000160 seconds (6 allocations: 200.359 KiB)
  0.017443 seconds (12 allocations: 3.907 MiB)

14
  0.000302 seconds (7 allocations: 400.281 KiB)
  0.018941 seconds (12 allocations: 7.813 MiB)

15
  0.000591 seconds (7 allocations: 800.281 KiB)
  0.016249 seconds (6 allocations: 3.125 MiB)

16
  0.001143 seconds (7 allocations: 1.563 MiB)
  0.016624 seconds (6 allocations: 6.250 MiB)

17
  0.002178 seconds (7 allocations: 3.125 MiB)
  0.013382 seconds

18
  0.004379 seconds (7 allocations: 6.250 MiB)
  0.011950 seconds

19
  0.008678 seconds (7 allocations: 12.500 MiB)
  0.012182 seconds

20
  0.032966 seconds (7 allocations: 25.000 MiB, 47.46% gc time)
  0.013622 seconds

21
  0.033038 seconds (7 allocations: 50.000 MiB)
  0.015635 seconds

22
  0.089011 seconds (7 allocations: 100.000 MiB, 24.47% gc time)
  0.021704 seconds


  0.137010 seconds (1.43 k allocations: 30.063 MiB, 41.84% compilation time)
  0.079798 seconds (130 allocations: 30.003 MiB)
  0.080075 seconds (130 allocations: 30.003 MiB)
```

I find that dict is faster than sparsevec, but I want to make it faster.
So I want to know how can I find a efficient hash function for my case.

Comment: might be good to get some sample data

Comment: Without knowing your specific situation, it will be very difficult to suggest an efficient lookup algorithm that works in all cases. For instance, if you have infinite cache available, you can use the binary keys as integers and directly address memory locations in an array, ignoring sparsity entirely. If your processor has [ABM extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_Bit_manipulation_instruction_set), you can use Julia's fast `count_ones` and `leading_zeros` functions to make a 2-dimensional lookup table. It really all depends on your specific situation, so more info would be useful.

Comment: My integers may have bigger than 30bits, so can't directly use array of size 2^30.

Answer (score 0):

First, [don't use global variables](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-untyped-global-variables) for benchmarking or for critical code.  Read the Julia [performance tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/) — this is the second tip.

With regards to your original question: it's certainly possible to use a custom hashing function that speeds up hashing, simply by wrapping your `Dict` keys in a custom type that has it's own `Base.hash` method.  For example, see this [example of speeding up integer hashing](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/poor-time-performance-on-dict/9656/14?u=stevengj).